# Office Fabric React Nav Icons not shown and iconClassName not being applied

Tags: reactjs, office-fabric

My nav items need to have colour and icon changes.

I'm finding however that the set of icons I seem to have and the iconClassName do not seem to be being shown

```
{
    key: 'upload',
    name: 'MAU',
    icon: 'AlertSolid',
    iconClassName: 'bg-90',
    onClick: () => { return; },
    ['data-automation-id']: 'uploadNonFocusButton'
  }
```

It appears that there is a limited set of icons supported within the Nav and CommandBar. Is this correct? I'm also surprised that the iconClassName is not being picked up.